# mysql where clause give me an error

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, where-clause

```
| iID | saleID | cusID | date       | total | discount | advance | paid_status |

+-----+--------+-------+------------+-------+----------+---------+-------------+

|  16 |      1 |     1 | 2014-01-17 |  2400 |      100 |    1000 |           1 |

|  17 |      1 |     1 | 2014-02-17 |   240 |      100 |    1000 |           1 |

|  18 |      1 |     1 | 2013-03-17 |   280 |      100 |    1000 |           1 |

|  19 |      1 |     1 | 2014-04-18 |   120 |      100 |    1000 |           1 |
```

basically i have database shown above.i want to get sum of total for every month but for specific year

when i use this query it works but it doesn't give for only specific year as i don't specified year

```
SELECT sum(total) FROM `invoice_reg` group by month(date) ;
```

but when i use where clause like following it didn't work give me a error

```
SELECT sum(total) FROM `invoice_reg` group by month(date) where YEAR(date) = 2014
```

and i tried this one too.but faield too

```
SELECT sum(total) FROM `invoice_reg` group by month(date) where DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y')=2014
```

this is the error i'm getting

```
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where YEAR(date) = 2014
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: why not use google first?

Comment: Not sure about the functional requirement, but the syntax error you are getting is because you are having the where clause specified after the group by clause which is not right. group by clause always follow where clause.

Comment: @Abhi i used google and that's how i make above queries without well knowing mysql

Comment: This may be the correct version of the query you are looking for. I have not tested it though, **QUERY** SELECT
 month(date), sum(total)
FROM
 `invoice_reg`
where
 YEAR(date) = 2014
group by
 month(date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `where` before `group by`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Answer (score 2):

Try moving the `group by` statement to the end of the command

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way

```
SELECT monthly_total FROM 
     ( 
     SELECT 
        sum(total) as monthly_total,YEAR(date) as yr 
     FROM `invoice_reg` 
     GROUP BY month(date) 
     ) t
WHERE yr = 2014
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sum(total) FROM `invoice_reg` 
where YEAR(date) = year(now())
group by month(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT sum(total) 
FROM invoice_reg 
WHERE year(date) = 2014
GROUP BY month(date)
```